# Can Postgres DISTINCT ON return a count?

Tags: postgresql

If you have a Postgres query like this:

```sql
-- get top customer from each region
select distinct on (region) *
from customers
order by region, total_purchases desc
```

how could you add a count of how many customers were in each region? Similar to a `count(*)` in a `group by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allowed to use `count(*) over ()` in select clause:

```
select distinct on (region), count(*) over (partition by region) as customer_count, *
from customers
order by region, total_purchases desc
```